# Template arguments are invalid (unique pointer)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I am trying to make an N-dimensional array class that is dynamically resizable. My templated class has the signature `ndarray<typename data_type, int dimensions>`. To hold the array I want to use a unique pointer class member to hold a templated vector of the types `std::vector<type_t>` for 1D, `std::vector<std::vector<type_t>>` for 2D, `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<type_t>>>` for 3d ect...

The unique pointer will have a different signature depending on the number of dimensions. I wanted to have the class constructor for ndarray to set the signature of the unique pointer and use `new` to make the new vector but I would need an `auto` member variable to be set to  a vector of the type of the member variable which doesn't work. My current aproach is to use a templated function that returns an object of the type the array needs to be, `template<typename data_type> auto dimension_helper(int dimensions)` and then set the unique pointer signature like this `std::unique_ptr<decltype(<data_type>dimension_helper(dimens))> array`. This also does not work, giving me the errors template argument 1 is invalid and template argument 2 is invalid inside the unique pointer.

What can I do to make my existing code work, or is there a better way at approaching the problem in a similar way?

Code samples

header

```
#ifndef ND_H_
#define ND_H_
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


namespace NdArray{
    //use the following for dimension types 
    template<typename T>
    using d1 = std::vector<T>;
    template<typename T>
    using d2 = std::vector<d1<T>>;
    template<typename T>
    using d3 = std::vector<d2<T>>;
    template<typename T>
    using d4 = std::vector<d3<T>>;
    template<typename T>
    using d5 = std::vector<d4<T>>;

    template<typename data_type>
    auto dimension_helper(int dim);



    template<typename data_type,int dimensions>
    class ndarray{
            int dims;
            std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> xsub_spans;

        public:
            ndarray();
            ~ndarray();
            std::unique_ptr<decltype(<data_type>dimension_helper(dimensions))> array;

            template<typename dat_type, int dim>
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& , ndarray<dat_type, dim>&);
    };

}


#endif
```

definitions so far

```
#include "nd.h" 
using namespace NdArray;

template<typename data_type, int dimensions>
ndarray<data_type, dimensions>::ndarray(){
    dims = dimensions;
    array = new <data_type>dimension_helper(dimensions); 
}

template<typename data_type>
auto dimension_helper(){
    switch (dims) {
        case 1 : {
            d1<data_type> type;
            return type;
            break;
        }
        case 2 : {
            d2<data_type> type;
            return type;
            break;
        }
        case 3 : {
            d3<data_type> type;
            return type;
            break;
        }
        case 4 : {
            d4<data_type> type;
            return type;
            break;
        }
        case 5 : {
            d5<data_type> type;
            return type;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A template argument list comes *after* the template's name, so `dimension_helper<data_type>(dimensions)` instead of `<data_type>dimension_helper(dimensions)`

Comment: I made those changes and its just made my compiler even more mad haha.

Comment: [error] use of 'auto NdArray::dimension_helper(int) [with data_type = int]' before deduction of auto and [error] declaration of 'class std::unique_ptr<auto, std::default_delete<auto>>'

Comment: [OT]: `dims = dimensions;` is redundant, `dimensions` is accessible in the scope of `array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template argument list comes after the template's name, so:

```
dimension_helper<data_type>(dimensions)
```

instead of

```
<data_type>dimension_helper(dimensions)
```

However, your "dimension helper" has no chance to work, as the switch statement is a runtime branch, and fails to compile because the types of expressions in return statements are unequal. Instead, you can rewrite it as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { using type = T; };    
template <typename T, std::size_t D>
struct dimension_helper : identity<std::vector<typename dimension_helper<T, D-1>::type>> {};
template <typename T>
struct dimension_helper<T, 0> : identity<T> {};
template <typename T, std::size_t D>
using dimension_helper_t = typename dimension_helper<T, D>::type;
```

and declare your pointer as:

```
std::unique_ptr<dimension_helper_t<data_type, dimensions>> array;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a768cd9560ac416a)

Comment: Ok that makes some sense. Im going to have to pick through that for a bit to figure out exactly what you did there. But thank you :)